# Does the Kalman filter incorporate a Heisenberg-like uncertainty principle?

Tags: classical-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, observables, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

In the case of mechanical systems, applying [the Kalman filter](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mechanical-engineering/2-160-identification-estimation-and-learning-spring-2006/lecture-notes/lecture_7.pdf) involves combining model based prediction (using an *apriori* known dynamical model) with real-world noisy observations of the positions and velocities of the system. The algorithm weights the *apriori* prediction and current observation in proportion to the uncertainty (covariance) of the model and observation. Indeed, the *aposteriori* uncertainty (covariance) decreases to an equilibrium value on applying the algorithm iteratively as the number of observations of the positions and velocities of the systems grows. This indicates a bound on the available resolution of the filter even as we accrue an arbitrarily large number of observations.

Is there a direct correspondence between the filtering algorithm and the Heisenberg uncertainty principle in quantum mechanics? A similar [classical-quantum correspondence indeed exists in the case of *purely predictive* models of the Langevin systems or potential flows with additive Brownian noise](http://www.physics.utah.edu/%7Elebohec/ScaleRelativity/Papers/1966_ENelson_Derivation_of_SchrodEq_from_NewtMech.pdf), but I'm not aware of any work in the case of observations of noisy dynamics.